# Upload image directly to twitter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter

I need help in uploading images directly to twitter in Windows Phone 7.

I am done with oauth flow of twitter and can also could update tweets but I have not been able to upload image to twitter using wp7?

Comment: ...and if you are using a client library, which one, as you've tagged this question with more than one

Comment: i tried tweetsharp for windows phone . and also twitterizer for oauth flow and post a tweet . thanks for your responses :)

Comment: What code did you try with either?

Comment: through tweetsharp i could upload image only 2 twitpic.com but unable to post it in twitter. twitterizer doesn have provision to upload image directly to twitter.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I have tried both and Gokoulane is right. Neither libraries support image uploading to twitter, with the exception of twitpic support in TweetSharp. Of course it doesn't help that WP7 devs are usually last in line when it comes to support or samples from these API's compared to IOS and Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have worked out a solution for this, by using the Hammock.WindowsPhone.Mango library.
(TweetSharp internally uses Hammock library for oAuth and other functionalities, but I have never used TweetSharp or Twitterizer)

I have installed the latest version of Hammock from [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock)

And then the following code is used for photo upload to Twitter:

```
public void uploadPhoto(Stream photoStream, string photoName)
{
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
        {
            Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.consumerKeySecret,
            Token = TwitterSettings.accessToken,
            TokenSecret = TwitterSettings.accessTokenSecret,
            Version = "1.0a"
        };


        RestClient restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://upload.twitter.com",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true,
            Credentials = credentials,
            Method = WebMethod.Post
         };
         RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest
         {
            Path = "1/statuses/update_with_media.json"
         };

         restRequest.AddParameter("status", tbxNewTweet.Text);
         restRequest.AddFile("media[]", photoName, photoStream, "image/jpg");

}

    restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
}


private void PostTweetRequestCallback(RestRequest request, Hammock.RestResponse response, object obj)
{
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
        //Success code
        }
}
```

Here, 
photoName is the name of the image selected ( "e.OriginalFileName")
photoStream is the "e.ChosenPhoto" from the PhotoChooserTask

and the 4th parameter for .AddFile() should be taken care (I have not considered other formats while doing this sample, you have to take care in your apps)

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Is the MediaUpdateUrl supposed to be "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"?

Comment: Ok I changed that and everything appears to go smoothly but when I get the response back I'm getting an "UnAuthorized" message. Any idea why I might be getting this? I am passing in a valid token and token secret.

Comment: code is working fine for me, so My first guess is, whether you are passing valid tokens? As you are sure about it, my next thought is whether you are using latest version of Hammock library or not?

Comment: I did use hammock to get the tokens. While I was going through it though I didn't see any problems. I will have to check if I have the latest version of hammock. By the way is read/wrIte permissions sufficient for my app when requesting an apI key? I noticed when I sign into twitter it doesn't say anything about uploading media on my behalf.

Comment: Read/write permissions are sufficient. If you are able to post a normal status, then you are also able to upload image.
Also, try passing "form-data" string as a 5th parameter in AddFile().

Comment: It works perfect! After I added the 5th parameter I removed hammock and added the latest version which did the trick. Thanks for your help. I will award you the bounty in 8 hours.

Comment: Thx kishor chandra it really helped :)

Comment: Anyone know why I am getting a TypeLoadException -"Could not load type 'System.Action' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'." at the line: restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback)); I've tried everything but can't seem to find an answer

Comment: No overload of `AddFile` admits `Stream` as a parameter. `Byte[]` or `Action<Stream>` are available

Comment: Hi @loyalpenguin can you explain me how you removed and added the latest version of hammock, I removed the Hammock.WindowsPhone.dll from my reference and installed by use of "Install-Package Hammock" in package manager console, but it doesn't helps.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Twitter supports WP7 and has a TweetWithMedia method that works like this:

```
    private void PostButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TweetTextBox.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter text to tweet.");

        ITwitterAuthorizer auth = SharedState.Authorizer;
        if (auth == null || !auth.IsAuthorized)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OAuth.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

            var media = GetMedia();

            twitterCtx.TweetWithMedia(
                TweetTextBox.Text, false, StatusExtensions.NoCoordinate, StatusExtensions.NoCoordinate, null, false,
                media,
                updateResp => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    HandleResponse(updateResp);
                }));
        }
    }
```

Joe

Comment: How do you presereve the SharedState.Authorizer between applications runs so there is no need to authorize every time the app is run?

Comment: @IgorKulman, You can save the credentials instead of the authorizer. More info here: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/362342.